Calibration of Heston-Nandi GARCH Model Using Historical Data: Risk-Neutral vs. Physical Measure
I am currently working on calibrating the Heston-Nandi GARCH model using historical asset return data and am faced with a decision on whether to use the risk-neutral or physical measure for this purpose. I aim to utilize this model for option pricing, although the model does not inherently require risk-neutral pricing, but on the contrary. The physical measure model is described as follows:
$$
\log(S_{t}) = \log(S_{t-1}) + r - \lambda h_t + \sqrt{h_t} z_{t},
$$
$$
h_{t} = \omega + \beta h_{t-1} + \alpha \left(z_{t-1} - \gamma \sqrt{h_{t-1}}\right)^2
$$
where $S_t$ are stock prices, $r$ is risk free rate, $h_t$ variance and $z_t$ standard normal variable.
The risk-neutral dynamics of the Heston-Nandi GARCH model are obtained when we replace $\lambda$ with $-1/2$ and applying a correction of the parameter $ \gamma^* $, defined as:
$$
\gamma^* = \lambda + \gamma + \frac{1}{2},
$$
Given this setup, should I use the risk-neutral or the physical measure for calibration? What are the implications of choosing one over the other in terms of model accuracy and applicability? If you have any literature suggestions, please share them.

We usually estimate the parameters of the physical measure with return data and calibrate the parameters of the risk neutral measure using options data. Your question is not clear
